# Magento : Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend_Db_Statement_Exception

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

To put it shortly, I'm looking for a lifesaver... I'm in serious trouble with this

I had a working `Magento 1.7` installation, there was some problem with a plugin named `worldpay`, so I checked for various upgrades via magento connect and was upgrading. While trying to upgrade Mage core or something like that, it shown me an error.

Since then `500 internal server error` was showing. So, I used magento cleanup tool and now I was stuck with `503 error`.

I removed `maintenance.flag` file and now I'm stuck with this error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend_Db_Statement_Exception::getPrevious() in /home/****/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 351
```

I cannot get rid of it. No google solution here... Is there someone who can help me???

I'm ready to pay for it too.

The site has a huge database (1.5GB) , so no reinstall here.
Please

Thanks

Comment: For PHP < 5.3.0, provides access to the getPrevious() method.

Comment: Oh sorry... you mean I need to upgrade my PHP to 5.3? But php 5.3 is not a requirement of Magento if I'm not wrong

Comment: This is not related to PHP 5.3.0, as we are talking about Zend Framework's getPrevious() method. What error did you get while upgrading ?

Comment: I think you are right Jevgeni. The error was "Exception during cache and session cleaning" . And there were some conflicts too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, go to index.php and see if developer mode is off by checking lines

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}

#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

If the developer mode was off or if switching it off didn't help, go to `/home/****/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 351` and see what's going on.

Magento can not find `Zend_Db_Statement_Exception::getPrevious()` method for some reason, so either comment this out and see what is going to happen or search entire directory for `getPrevious()` method and correct the reference `Zend_Db_Statement_Exception` if this method happens to be in some other place.

If this doesn't help, try to run the upgrade script again.

If after this it is still a problem, you will probably need to hire a developer to fix it. There are plenty of freelancers, who would be happy to do it.

Comment: Thanks. Very promising answer and I tried them all just now. There is no getPrevious() function calling anywhere. I've searched with powergrep even...

Is this the result of a half upgrade? Maybe zend framework got upgraded but magento did not? or vice versa?

And if you don't mind, do you have some time to spend and help here? It's tough to find someone reliable. I'll understand if you're busy.

Comment: Somehow, I fixed it. Merged random files from backup. You never know what might get you out of gutter. Thank you friend! For keeping me motivated!

I'm marking your answer as correct as it may help others fix.